# To count number of events occuring in large data in r

Tags: r

Hello I have a large data set, part of which might look something like this.

```
Seconds <- c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24)
B<- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
C<-c(50, 60, 62, 65, 80, 60, 68, 66, 60, 69, 70, 89)
mydata<- data.frame(Seconds, B, C)
```

I am stuck in the analysis of this type of data. Getting straight to the problem, I need 
Number of times C<80 for continuously more than 6 seconds and 10 seconds.

in this case

N6(C<80 for more than 6 seconds)=4

N10(C<80 for more than 10 seconds)=1

I hope this makes sense! Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: It is helpful if you provide some code to recreate you example as 'Seconds <- c(2,4,6,8,10...   This way it's easier for people who want to answer to test their solutions. I would look into ?which somewhat like which(df$C<81 & df$seconds<6)

Comment: For the 2nd case, wouldn't it be `2`

Comment: @akrun Thank you, Yes that is a mistake(it is C<80), I will edit that, I am trying the answer you have given, but as my data is large with NA values it is taking a while.

Comment: @JonGrub I have edited the question according to your comment. Sorry this is my first question on this website, comments will also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

We can do

```
 with(mydata, sum(C<80 & Seconds>=6 & B!=0))
 #[1] 4
```

It could be also

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(mydata)[Seconds>=6 & B!=0, sum(C<80), rleid(B)]
```

Comment: This does not seem to work with different conditions, like C<65 for more than 4 seconds

Comment: @M.Madhu  May be the way in which you described the problem is not clear.  For the second case in your post, I am getting a count of 2.

Comment: The exact question would be: The **number of times(events)** value in column C remains less than 80 for continuously more than 10 seconds(more than 5 rows) in the entire data. In my actual data I have 322375 rows with Seconds value upto 644750. I hope I am able to explain my problem well.

Comment: @M.Madhu  I understand the description, but the expected output in your result is not the same.  You can count `N10(C<80 for more than 10 seconds)`

Comment: from 6ht to 11th row it is more than 10 seconds with C<80, therefore the count i should get is 1.

Comment: @M.Madhu  For row 6, Seconds is 12, C is 60, row 7, Seconds is 14, C is 68, row 8, Seconds is 16, C is 66, row 9 Seconds is 18 C is 60, row 10 Seconds is 20 C is 69, row 11 Seconds is 22 and C is 70.  Tell me how the count will be 1?  I removed the rows where B is equal to 0 and still it comes to 2.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest this modest [**`dplyr`**](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)-based solution

```
# Libs
Vectorize(require)(package = c("dplyr", "magrittr"),
                   char = TRUE)
# Summary
mydata %<>%
  mutate(criteria = ifelse(Seconds >= 6 & C < 80, TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
  group_by(criteria) %>% 
  tally()
```

## Preview

```
> head(mydata)
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

  criteria     n
     (lgl) (int)
1    FALSE     4
2     TRUE     8
```